# Making JettyRunner serve up static content (like CSS and JavaScript) with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, jetty

I'm running a Java project via Jetty Runner (7.6.15). I've been trying to play with D3.js lately, and I needed to serve it up unminified in order to debug some mystery problem. Well, D3 has some non-Latin Unicode characters in some variable names (like `var π = Math.PI`).

When I try to use that unminified file, I get errors because my browser thinks the character encoding is ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8. Sure enough, the "Content-Type" header in the server response has no character set.

I'm launching Jetty Runner with `LANG` and `LC_ALL` both set to "en_US.UTF-8", and I'm passing a system property `file.encoding` set to "UTF-8" as well on the Java command line. That apparently is not enough. I can look at the source file on my host and it's definitely intact; in fact if I load the JavaScript file directly from the browser address bar and *manually* tell Firefox that it's Unicode, then it looks fine.

I'm not launching Jetty Runner with a configuration file because I have no idea how to do that. It seems to add an explicit ISO-8859-1 marker to the content type header on the main HTML page (it's a single-page application), and that of course overrides the `<meta charset>` tag in the document head.

So is there a way to do this? Sometimes I feel like I'm one of the only 12 people on earth who use Jetty Runner :)

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be as simple as a clause in my `web.xml`:

```
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>js</extension>
    <mime-type>application/javascript; charset=UTF-8</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
```

I don't know how something this obvious escaped my notice. It doesn't even have much to do with Jetty per se.